# Updating label using Timer

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a several labels that gets filled with strings and i want my timer will fill those strings every 500 milliseconds.
my problem i try to debug my code and it seems that my timer did not work at all:

This is my class event that pass all this 5 parameters that i want my labels will fill:

```
void MyClass_statusChangedEvent(string status, int packets, int packetsProgress, double bps, double pps)
{
    MyObj obj = new MyObj(status, packets, packetsProgress, bps, pps);
    timerStatus.Tag = obj;
    timerStatus.Interval = 500;            
    timerStatus.Start();
}
```

**MyObj obj...** is my object that hold this 5 parameters and pass it to my timer.
all the members from this class has getter.

and this is my timer tick:

```
    private void timerStatus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //update label here
    }
```

Comment: try adding `timerStatus.Enabled = true;`

Comment: Does your Tick method start getting called after MyClass_statusChangedEvent fires up? Are you sure the event is linked up to the controller? try adding `timerStatus.Tick += new EventHandler(timerStatus_Tick);` if that doesn't work, see if you can get the timer to works if it's instantiated and setup outside of your MyClass_statusChangedEvent method. Perhaps in the form's init method.

Comment: Your logic seems completely off. Guessing from the name of your MyClass_statusChangedEvent method, that is the method that should do the updating of the label, not a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
   timerStatus.Tick += new EventHandler(timerStatus_Tick);
```

before

```
    timerStatus.Interval = 500;
```

Comment: and how can i pass all this 5 parameters to my timer ?

Comment: If your properties are going to be updated outside of `MyClass_statusChangedEvent` and you need their updated values, you should probably grab them from outside of `timerStatus_Tick` instead of having them passed by `MyClass_statusChangedEvent`. There are better ways to do this, I suggest trying to get it to work first and then try to clean it up :) good luck